# I'm having trouble understanding why my method of solving a specific combinatorics deck of cards question doesn't work.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

QUESTION: A poker hand of five cards is dealt from a standard pack of 52. Find the probability of obtaining two pairs.

My method is as follows: 13C1 (choose value of first pair) x 4C2 (choose suits of pair) x 12C1 (choose value of second pair, cannot be same as first pair) x 4C2 (choose suits of second pair) x 11C1 (choose value of last card) x 4C4 (suit of last card). Then put that over 52C5.

The answer, however, is (13C2×4C2×4C2×11C1×4), which yields a different result. I understand why the answer is correct but not why my method is incorrect, if anyone can offer a solution it would be heavily appreciated.

Comment: You are double counting.  You count $XXYYZ$ and $YYXXZ$ as two different hands.  But I also think you have a arithmetic error in your calculation...surely the last factor is meant to be $4$ ($=\binom 41$) and not $1=\binom 44$.  With that correction you should see that your method gives twice the other.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand why the answer is correct but not why my method is
> incorrect...

Your method regards the order of the first and second pairs as consequential. So $(4♣,4♠,A♥,A♠,\_)$ and $(A♥,A♠,4♣,4♠,\_)$ are counted as two, when they are one and the same.

Divide by $2$ to compensate for this and you should get the same answer.